# I have installed Valheim as a service how can I connect to it's running process and view the console?

Tags: command-line, server

I have installed a dedicated Valheim server following a step by step video on youtube.  I have it launching as a service automatically when the server boots up and I can launch it directly using a script.  What I would like to do is connect to the running process and input commands directly via the console.  I would also like to monitor the server console for connects and disconnects so I can see when users log on and off in real time.  I do this with screen generally on my minecraft servers but the walk thru didn't include those steps.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  TIA!!!